# Java: I keep on getting an odd output

Tags: java

Whenever I run this code I keep on getting:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

at UseEmployeeRecord.main(UseEmployeeRecord.java:24)
```

as an output.

```
// The "UseEmployeeRecord" class.
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;
import java.io.*;


public class UseEmployeeRecord {

   public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

       BufferedReader fr = new BufferedReader (new FileReade("employees.txt"));
        String name;
        int num;
        double hr, hw;

        EmployeeRecord employee[] = new EmployeeRecord [10];

        for (int i = 0 ; i < employee.length ; i++)
        {
            name= fr.readLine ();
            num = Integer.parseInt (fr.readLine ());
            hr = Double.parseDouble (fr.readLine ());
            hw = Double.parseDouble (fr.readLine ());

            employee [i] = new EmployeeRecord (name, num, hr, hw);

       }
   }
}
```

Comment: `null` is not a number! Ehat is the Content of your file

Answer (score 0):

You have not pasted the contents of employees.txt

Exception is clear.

If the value from employees.txt is String representation of "Integer" e.g

`Integer.parseInt("1")` will not throw exception but for sure `Integer.parseInt(null)` or `Integer.parseInt("x")`  will throw exception. So for debugging, print the value of `readLine` and see if it really represents an integer.

Comment: Why would OP need to print the value for "debugging"? The exception message can't be more clear: `null` has been passed, meaning the file end has been reached.

Comment: @Tom because null is not where he will stop. What if next line is not a number? He shall know what he is reading.

Comment: If he runs the program again, with a different set of data as i assume the content of file may change.

Comment: Re-running the program with different data wouldn't change the fact that there is no need to print the result of `fr.readLine()` for debugging, beacuse the behaviour is the same as long as the file is too short. If the file were correct (or long enough), then OP would either don't get any exception or a different one. And the received exception (in the question) makes it very clear that the file is too short.

Comment: And you first comment (the response to my first comment) still doesn't make sense when you re-running the whole application.